# Error replacing XML element contents with maven-replacer-plugin

Tags: xml, maven, replace, bamboo

I'm using maven-replacer-plugin to alter a value in an XML file as part of a build.

The XML file contains this element, which I need to replace:

```
 <id>foo</id>
```

I have the following in my POM:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>replacer</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>process-resources
                    </phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>replace</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <file>${pom.basedir}/${air.app.descriptor}</file>
                <replacements>
                    <replacement>
                        <token>&lt;id&gt;.*&lt;/id&gt;</token>
                        <value>&lt;id&gt;id.${application.name}.${environment.name}.${project.version}&lt;/id&gt;</value>
                    </replacement>
                </replacements>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

This works fine when I build locally. However, on our CI build server (Bamboo) I get the following error:

```
[INFO] --- replacer:1.5.3:replace (default) @ app-main ---
[ERROR] named capturing group is missing trailing '}'
[INFO] Replacement run on 0 file.
```

Both machines are Windows.

---

**Update:**

I modified my replacement to use XPATH:

```
<replacement>
    <xpath>/application/id/text()</xpath>
    <token>^.*$</token>
    <value>${application.name}.${environment.name}.${project.version}</value>
</replacement>
```

And now my error is slightly different, but the problem seems to be the same:

```
[INFO] --- replacer:1.5.3:replace (default) @ app-main ---
[ERROR] Error during XML replacement: named capturing group is missing trailing '}'
[INFO] Replacement run on 0 file.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question.
The error message is confusing. One of the properties was not available on the CI configuration. For some reason, the replacer plugin does not allow the text in `<value>` to contain `{`, and an error is thrown, even though the error text makes it appear to be an error in the Regexp.